# Where to Record How and When Your iOS App Was Opened

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I want to capture data each time a user opens my app. I know that all roads in `AppDelegate.m` eventually lead to `applicationDidBecomeActive`, but is there a best practice for capturing app opens?

I want to know if the app was opened via a Push Notification, a URL request, or directly through the App Icon. I could record all these separately in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, etc, but I think I need to always have the 'direct' open recorded in `applicationDidBecomeActive` ... but the only way I can work it all out is to use a OPEN_RECORDED flag, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSDictionary* notification =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];


    if (notification) {
        [self recordStat:@“remoteNotification”];
    } else {
        [self recordStat:@“directOpen”];
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self recordStat:@“directOpen”];

    // Reset OPEN_RECORDED for next time
    self.OPEN_RECORDED = NO;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    if (application.applicationState==UIApplicationStateInactive ||
        application.applicationState==UIApplicationStateBackground)  {
        [self recordStat:@“remoteNotification”];
    } 

}


// Handle Custom URL Scheme
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    [self recordStat:@“customURL”];

    return YES;
}

-(void)recordStat:(NSString*)stat {
    if (!self.OPEN_RECORDED) { 
        // Upload the stat to my server
        // CODE HERE

        // Set the OPEN_RECORDED flag
        self.OPEN_RECORDED = YES;
    }       
}
```

but the flag just seems silly ... is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand why are you using OPEN_RECORDED. Could you please explain? Maybe you are trying to distinguish between first launch and become active?

Comment: If the app is opened via push notification, it first hits `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and then hits `applicationDidBecomeActive`, which would result in two different calls to the `recordStat` method.

Comment: Why not just use Parse? You can easily check to see when an app is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"recorded"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And then check launched value your record method:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"recorded"]) {
    // Not recorded
} else {
    // Launch recorded
}
```

I think this approach is better because you can implement recordStat method in another class (outside `AppDelegate`). You can check `NSUserDefaults` values anywhere.

You can record the kind of launch (direct, push notifications or url) and call method recordStat once (and pass the value of kind of launch) on method `applicationDidBecomeActive`. This way you do your code neater.